# How to practice a song?

Tags: practice, voice, melody

Few weeks ago I've started recording some vocal covers (rock/metal). But on recordings I've made I noticed some issues with exact note/melody matching.
Can anybody give me advice how to learn song melody precisely? Singing with a original track is not efficient enough because it contains lyrics which can disturb hearing exact note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sing along with a piano/guitar that is playing the melody.

I believe this will be really efficient, because you'll hear the exact melody and you'll see where exactly is your problem, and you can work on it. I believe the piano would be best, as it has really clear overtones that will help you listen to a crystal clear melody.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Bad thing is, that I'll have to find some piano versions of the songs.

Comment: @PhilMobile not necessarily. You can simply play the melody on the piano, so as to hear it clearly and then sing it along with the group

Comment: Ok, so I have to buy a piano now and start learning to play :)

Comment: You can find someone that already does to help you